# Monotone increasing/decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $s_1=k$ and define $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{4s_n-1}$ for $n\ge\ 1$. Determine for what values of k the sequence $(s_n)$ will be monotone increasing and for what values of k it will be monotone decreasing.

Ok, so I know that for a sequence to be monotone it must be increasing or decreasing, and $(s_n)$ is increasing if $s_n\le\ s_{n+1}$ and decreasing if $s_n\ge\ s_{n+1}$.

So for this I have to find which values of k result in $s_n\le\ s_{n+1}$ and which result in $s_n\ge\ s_{n+1}$.

Starting with $s_1=k$
then $s_{1+1}=s_{2}=\sqrt{4s_1-1}=\sqrt{4k-1}$.

So for it to be increasing, $\sqrt{4k-1}\ge\ k$
and for it to be decreasing, $\sqrt{4k-1}\le\ k$.

And I am kind of stuck from here:

So I found for what values of $k$, $s_2=k$:
$k^2=4k-1$,
$k=2+\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Should one of those "increasing"s in the second sentence be "decreasing"?

Comment: @CameronBuie yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  We have
$$\eqalign{s_{n+1}-(2+\sqrt3)
  &=\sqrt{4s_n-1}-(2+\sqrt3)\cr
  &=4\frac{s_n-(2+\sqrt3)}{\sqrt{4s_n-1}+(2+\sqrt3)}\ .\cr}$$
This shows that if $s_n>2+\sqrt3$ then
$$s_{n+1}-(2+\sqrt3)>0$$
and
$$s_{n+1}-(2+\sqrt3)<s_n-(2+\sqrt3)\ ,$$
that is,
$$2+\sqrt3<s_{n+1}<s_n\ .$$
So if we start with $k>2+\sqrt3$ then $s_n$ is always greater than $2+\sqrt3$ and always decreasing.

See if you can work out the other cases for yourself.  You will need to think carefully about what happens if $k\le 2-\sqrt3$.

Comment: To show that $s_n$ is decreasing, you need to show that $4 < \sqrt{4s_n-1}+2+\sqrt{3}$. Not difficult, but not obvious.

Comment: Also, I think you  should mention that the magic number $2+\sqrt{3}$ is the fixed point of the iteration.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks for the comments, you are right, but please see the first word of my answer ;-)

Comment: @David thanks for your explanation, I guess I am a little bit confused sitll about the second line in your first equation, could you explain to me how you got that?

Comment: @MathMajor rationalise $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$ by multiplying by $\sqrt a+\sqrt b$ in numerator and denominator, then do a bit of easy algebra.

Comment: @David ok and would you mind explaining how you knew to take $s_{n+1}-2+\sqrt3$? I know that when $k=2+\sqrt3$ then S1=S2 but I am a little unsure of how you knew to do that step

Comment: If you assume $s_n$ has a limit $L$ then $L=\sqrt{4L-1}$ so $L=2\pm\sqrt3$.  This indicates that these numbers are important.  If you then try plotting values with software (eg, Maple) it seems clear that when you start above $2+\sqrt3$ the sequence is always decreasing to $2+\sqrt3$.  This is the same as saying $s_n-(2+\sqrt3)$ is always decreasing to $0$.  So then you do the algebra to try and prove it carefully.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $0<x<1$, then $\sqrt x>x$, and if $x>1$, then $\sqrt x<x$. Also, for what value of $k$ is $s_2=k$?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow..

Comment: @MathMajor: What happens if $k>\frac12$? That's not the whole story, but it should get you started.